Block a PROXMOX virtual machine or container from accessing the Internet
On my server with PROXMOX, I want to prevent certain virtual machines and containers from accessing the Internet.
Specifically, I would like to block any requests that do not fall within the IP range 192.168.*.*. What is the best way to configure this restriction?
I have tried looking into the network settings of PROXMOX, but I am not sure what the correct approach is.
Is there a built-in solution in PROXMOX to manage this type of restriction, or do I need to configure specific firewall rules?

Wouldn’t removing the virtual network adapter accomplish what you want?

No, it wouldn't solve the problem because the machine would no longer be accessible from the local network. Or maybe I'm wrong?

First of all you need to tell whether the VMs are bridged to any existing/physical network.

@Pinguto- You didn’t mention it needed to access the local network

What we typically do is add a container with a Mikrotik Router OS on it to create a virtual network inside proxmox. All VM's are connected to the internet, but the Guest OS are connected to that Mikrotik. From there, you can configure blocks and what can access the internet. In addition, you can do things like VPN tunnels, open ports, whitelist IP addresses, etc.
